# Numbers not showing in references

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, numbering

I'm working in a report and I can't make the references work the way I want to. My main problem is that, in the references section, the number in square brackets at the beginning of the reference doesn't show up. I've already looked up over the Internet for possible solutions, but none of them worked. I would be very grateful if someone could help me out. Following, it's the part of my code I consider relevant:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[sort, numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}  % Hyperlinks bib references.
\begin{document}

(...)

...esfera del hardware \cite{ocp} \cite{ocp2} \cite{ocp3}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\bibliography{referencias}

\end{document}
```

And here is my .bib file

```
@misc{ocp,
 number = {1},
 author = {OPC},
 title = {About Open Compute Project},
 url = {https://www.opencompute.org/about},
 year = {2018},
 note = {Último acceso: 03-11-2018}
}

@misc{ocp2,
 number = {2},
 author = {OPC2},
 title = {About Open Compute Project 2},
 url = {https://www.opencompute.org/about},
 year = {2018},
 note = {Último acceso: 03-11-2018}
}

@misc{ocp3,
 number = {3},
 author = {OPC3},
 title = {About Open Compute Project 3},
 url = {https://www.opencompute.org/about},
 year = {2018},
 note = {Último acceso: 03-11-2018}
}
```

[image: Here is the output for my references section]

As you can see there is no number between square brackets in the references. That's what I'd like to fix. Thank you.

Comment: If I try, I get the numbers. Please, let us know what document class you're using, which might change something about the choice of the options to `natbib`.

Comment: I've already added the document class and the citations in the text. I use an article class (I always use that class, to be honest) and \cite{}.

Comment: @anmomu `apacite` is the culprit, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `apacite` that defines its own style for the references, using the author-year system and so omitting the numbers next to the references.

By the way, `number` is a BibTeX field completely unrelated to bibliography item numbers and rather refers to numbers of a serial publication such as a journal; it is ignored in a `@misc` entry.