# How to indicate references by number(s) in square brackets in the section of refs?

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, elsarticle, authoryear

I set the references as the following in my document in Overleaf (`\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}`).

[image]

Now, I want to change it and indicate references by number(s) in square brackets in the text and also in the section of references, as shown in the figure. I could change it in the text but not in the section of references.
I have also seen [link1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/458261/numbers-not-showing-in-references) and [link2](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_with_bibtex).

How to do it?

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\graphicspath{ {./figures/} }
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{apalike}


\usepackage{lipsum,capt-of,graphicx}
\usepackage{geometry}% Just for this example
%\usepackage[authoryear,longnamesfirst]{natbib}
%\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
%\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{natbib}
\let\printorcid\relax
\usepackage[wby]{callouts}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=false, font={footnotesize}]{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Fig. ,labelsep=period, justification=justified, singlelinecheck=off}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=newline,font=footnotesize, justification=justified, singlelinecheck=off}%,skip=0pt,belowskip=0pt}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{\sffamily}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx, multirow}
\sisetup{table-format=1.4, tight-spacing=true, separate-uncertainty}

\sisetup{
    output-exponent-marker = \text{e},
    exponent-product={},
    retain-explicit-plus,
    input-open-uncertainty  = ,
    input-close-uncertainty = ,
    table-align-text-pre    = false,
    table-align-text-post = false,
    round-mode=places,
    round-precision=2,
    table-space-text-pre    = (,
    table-space-text-post   = ),
}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\floatsetup[table]{captionskip=0.1pt}

\usepackage{array, cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{3pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{3pt}

\usepackage{placeins}

\journal{J}

\bibliographystyle{model5-names}\biboptions{authoryear}
%\bibliographystyle{unsrt}\biboptions{numbers}


\begin{document}

For more information read \cite{AmericanL} and ...


\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

And here is a sample of my .bib file

```
@misc{AmericanL,
    HOWPUBLISHED = {\url{https://www.lung.org}},
    AUTHOR = {Association, American Lung},
    TITLE = {Lung Cancer Fact Sheet},
    MONTH = {Dec},
    YEAR = {2020},
    NOTE = {Accessed on 2020-12-1}
}
```

Comment: Off-topic: `AUTHOR = {Association, American Lung},` is *completely wrong*, at it tells BibTeX it's dealing with an author with surname `Association` and given names `American` and `Lung`. The field really has to be `AUTHOR = {{American Lung Association}},`. Note the use of double braces, which serve to inform BibTeX that the entry has a so-called "corporate" author.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10808/35864.

Comment: Remove `\biboptions{authoryear}`, all lines in your preamble that load `natbib` and the `\biboptions{authoryear}`. Then pass the option `number` to the *class* to get numeric citations (`\documentclass[review,number]{elsarticle}`).

Comment: @moewe: Yes, but my problem remains in the section of references.  In the References, it should be => [1] Association, A. L. , ...

Comment: Ah, I copy-and-pasted the wrong thing, sorry about that. The steps are as follows: (1) remove `\usepackage{apalike}`, (2) remove all lines loading `natbib` (currently only `\usepackage{natbib}` is active, but you should probably remove the commented lines as well to avoid confusion), (3) remove `\biboptions{authoryear}`. Then rerun the compilation.

Comment: You should also think about cleaning up your preamble. For journal submission it is usually a good idea to load as few packages as possible. In particular you should not load packages that change the underlying typesetting of the document (I'm thinking `setspace`, `geometry` as well as `caption` and your `\captionsetup` lines).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instruction `\biboptions{authoryear}` instructs the `natbib` citation package (which is loaded *automatically* by the `elsarticle` document class) to create authoryear-style citation call-outs. Since you say you don't want authoryear-style citation call-outs, stop using that instruction. Either delete the instruction outright or change it to `\biboptions{numbers}`.

Since you employ the `elsarticle` document class, you can't go very wrong by using the `elsarticle-num` bib style. In consequence, don't load the `model5-names` bib style.

And, since you're using the `elsarticle` document class, which loads the `natbib` citation management package automatically, do get rid of the `\usepackage{apalike}` instruction. The `apalike` and `natbib` citation management packages are not mutually compatible.

Finally, since `American Lung Association is not a person with two given names and one surname, you need to write

```
AUTHOR = {{American Lung Association}},
```

in order to inform BibTeX that the entry has a co-called "corporate" author.

[image]

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{sample.bib}
@misc{AmericanL,
    HOWPUBLISHED = {\url{https://www.lung.org}},
    AUTHOR = {{American Lung Association}},
    TITLE  = {Lung Cancer Fact Sheet},
    MONTH  = {Dec},
    YEAR   = {2020},
    NOTE   = {Accessed on 2020-12-1}
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\usepackage{xurl} % allow arbitrary line breaks in URL strings
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}
For more information read \cite{AmericanL} and \dots
\bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```